# nsis installer autoexits/ closes automatically , i am using pre and show functions to show a directory MUI page

Tags: installation, crash, custom-controls, nsis, modern-ui

i am building an installer using nsis. i have added 5 buttons using resource hacker on the Directory Page Dialog of the installer. also i have defined these functions:

```
      !define IDC_BUTTON_CDRIVEPATH         1200
      !define IDC_BUTTON_DDRIVEPATH         1201
      !define IDC_BUTTON_EDRIVEPATH         1202
      !define IDC_BUTTON_FDRIVEPATH         1203
      !define IDC_BUTTON_GDRIVEPATH         1204

!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\licensefile.txt"

    !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE DirectoryPre
    !define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW DirectoryShow

      !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

      !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
      !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
      !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

---

```
Function DirectoryShow

  GetFunctionAddress $R0 DDRIVEPATH
  ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_BUTTON_DDRIVEPATH} $R0
FunctionEnd
```

---

```
Function DirectoryPre

  GetFunctionAddress $R6 EDRIVEPATH
  ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_BUTTON_EDRIVEPATH} $R6

line 1--      GetFunctionAddress $R7 FDRIVEPATH
line 2--      ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_BUTTON_FDRIVEPATH} $R7

line 3--      GetFunctionAddress $R8 GDRIVEPATH
line 4--      ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_BUTTON_GDRIVEPATH} $R8

FunctionEnd
```

---

When i do not remove the two handlers **FDRIVEPATH** & **GDRIVEPATH**,i.e. when i do not remove the lines--LINE 1,2,3,4, then,-------------when i goto COMPONENTS page, and press the BACK button to go back to the DIRECTORY page, then the installer exits automatically. i don't know why its happening.? please help? am stuck with it since two days.

BUT, when i remove the two handlers **FDRIVEPATH** & **GDRIVEPATH**,i.e. when i remove the lines--LINE 1,2,3,4, then, the installer runs properly.

I want all the handlers for these five buttons. i dont want to remove any of them.

FOLLOWING IS MY DIRECTORY PAGE DIALOG:---------
[image]

Comment: How is this going to scale? There can be 26 drive letters...

Comment: @Anders : sir, i din't understand what do you mean to say? please elaborate.

Comment: i only want to give option of F and G, but atleast it should work? but it doesn't

Comment: @sqlchild: You don't have enough space for 26 drive buttons. Maybe the user wants to pick A: or Z:, you don't know where other people have mounted their drives. Also, it looks like you have disabled the browse button, this is not a good idea since a drive can be mounted in a folder: C:\Somefolder\DriveD

Comment: @Anders : ok sir, but i will tell my users that they can type in the letter if their drive is some different one, but atleast my buttons should work ?

Comment: @Anders : sir , please have a look at this post, my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870048/nsis-installer-file-copy-operation-not-working

Comment: @Anders : sir, please help, what's the error on the code posted on this post, i am still struggling with the button event handling, when i remove button F and G ,  then it works, but when i don't then it automatically exits

Comment: @sqlchild: I have never used that plugin so I can't help you with it...

Comment: @sqlchild: There is a new version of the plugin just released now, maybe it fixes your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Use ComboBox or ListBox which will be filled with all drives letters to save space.

ComboBox created with nsDialogs:

```
Var CB_Buttons

${NSD_CreateComboBox} 0 20 32% 100 ""
Pop $CB_Buttons
   ${NSD_CB_AddString} $CB_Buttons "A:\" 
   ${NSD_CB_AddString} $CB_Buttons "B:\"
   ${NSD_CB_AddString} $CB_Buttons "C:\"
etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

THE BUTTON EVENT PLUGIN WAS HAVING A BUG, WHICH HAS BEEN FIXED BY THE PLUG-IN DEVELOPER, Mr. Afrow UK.