# NSIS installer file copy operation not working

Tags: installation, nsis, file-copying

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section

!define FileCopy `!insertmacro FileCopy`
!macro FileCopy FilePath TargetDir
  CreateDirectory `${TargetDir}`
  CopyFiles `${FilePath}` `${TargetDir}`
!macroend

  ${FileCopy} 'E:\BACKUP\' 'E:\BACKUPNEW\'

SectionEnd
```

--it gives error: Never had OUTFILE command.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, makensis is telling you the problem: "Never had OUTFILE command"

A script **must** have a outfile command.

```
Outfile "mysetup.exe"
Page InstFiles ;You can omit this, but the compiler will give you a warning
Section
SectionEnd
```